# Give focus to non-form element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jhtmlarea

Am just wondering if there is a way to give focus to a non-form element. I am asking because I am using the jhtmlArea plugin (http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/ - page currently down) in a project. And it does work, except that since it masks an IFRAME over a TEXTAREA the IFRAME, not being a form element, doesn't seem to want to receive focus. I think the demo on the official plugin page may have shown the IFRAME getting focus on load but I can't remember for sure and can't check now due to the plugin demo page not loading.

Comment: Try `attr('tabIndex', 0)`

Comment: http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/ - page back up now and their demo doesn't seem to show the IFRAME editor field automatically getting focus.

Comment: elclanrs, thanks. Tried your suggestion. It's not working right off the bat. Here's a jsfiddle that shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/7kTrB/6/

tabindex seems to only apply to form and A elements.

Comment: Curiously, the cursor does appear where you expect it to be once you click in the faux field and start typing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work in my project but for some reason when I put the solution into the jsfiddle it only works in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/7kTrB/8/

The following line seems to be the most relevant part:

```
this.iframe[0].contentWindow.focus();
```